# How to display image on WordPress homepage

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to display an image through my home page in WordPress, through my text editor on the page, but nothing displays. It works on other pages, just not on the home page. When I press publish, it says `updated` but when I check the source code nothing shows up for the image. If I publish it through css it works to get it displayed 
,but can't select the image in the way I could if I enclosed it in a div class. If I display it through a homepage text widget, it publishes twice, in different sizes-once in the body and once in the footer.

Image html

```
<div class="fbfp"><img src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/IMG_20200601_134623-300x279.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="279" class="size-medium wp-image-16023" /></div>
```

And html controlling homepage.

```
<section class="content- 
area  pt0 "><div id="main" 
class="" role="main">
<div 
id="shapely_home_parallax- 
 2" class="widget 
shapely_home_parallax">      
<section class="cover 
fullscreen image-bg">
<div class="parallax-window 
fullscreen" data- 
parallax="scroll" data- 
image- 
src="http://4309.co.uk/wp-  
content/uploads/2019/0
8/download-2.png" data-ios- 
fix="true" data-over- 
scroll-fix="true" data- 
android-fix="true">
<div class="align- 
transform">
<div class="row">
<div class="top-parallax- 
section">
```

Page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

Css

```
.fbfp {position:relative; bottom:300px;z-index: 100;}
```

`parallax-window` controls the home page I think.

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean by html controlling homepage? Html is the output, generated by php, you should look at index.php, or home.php or else, depending on your theme

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment. I'm just trying to find out what's causing the issue. Parallax-window is a text widget and just illustrates the set up I have and how css and other things are connected to it.